# Programatically generated UILabel origin point incorrectly to (0.0) set on first load

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uilabel, xcode4.5

I am trying to programatically generate two `UILabels` in my application for each `UIImageView` on my storyboard. The code runs and works correctly, however, on first load the two UILabels form in the (0.0) coordinate of the main view, as opposed to the UIImageView frame origin.x,origin.y. I can't understand why this is happening.

If I then click on a different tab and return to the page, the labels generate in the correct location.

Why is this? How can I get it to initially generate the labels in the correct location?

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //removed unneccessary code above...
    int i = 0;
    for (UIImageView *plantScreen in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([plantScreen isMemberOfClass:[Plant class]])
        {
            @try
            {
                //the label which will hold the name
                UILabel *plantName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((plantScreen.frame.origin.x), (plantScreen.frame.origin.y+ plantScreen.frame.size.height), 160, 30.0)];
                plantName.numberOfLines = 1;
                plantName.minimumScaleFactor = .5;
                plantName.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
                [plantName setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
                [plantName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

                [self.view addSubview:plantName];
                plantName.hidden = false; 
                [self.view bringSubviewToFront:plantName];

                //create the label which will hold the quantity
                UILabel *quantity = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((plantScreen.frame.origin.x), (plantScreen.frame.origin.y+ plantScreen.frame.size.height + 20), 160, 30.0)];

                [quantity setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
                [quantity setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                quantity.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",plant.quantity];
                [self.view addSubview:quantity];
                quantity.hidden = false;
                [self.view bringSubviewToFront:quantity];

                i++;   

            }
            @catch (NSException *exception)
            {   
                NSLog(@"An exception occured: %@", [exception reason]);
            }
            @finally
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you're missing a call to `[super viewWillAppear:animated]`. You need to give the superclass (including the `UIViewController` base class) a chance to "do its magic".

Never forget about giving the parent class a chance to do its magic, unless you know really really well what you're doing.

Second, UI creation should be done in `-loadView`, not in `viewWillAppear:`.

Try these two things first.

---

Alright. Now I'm curious about *how* you moved things to `-loadView`. Did you add `[super loadView];`?

In fact, now that I think about it, moving to `-loadView` is wrong in this case; you obviously instantiate some views through a nib. `UIViewController`'s implementation of `-loadView` typically just loads the nib file. Once that's done, `UIViewController`'s `-loadView` calls `-viewDidLoad`.

So when you're not creating all UI programmatically but are instead allowing `UIViewController` to load it from nib, you actually probably want to move code into `-viewDidLoad`. (See template generated by Xcode when you tell it to create a new `UIViewController` subclass.)

Moving on, let's consider what the frame depends on. It depends on some view class you called `Plant`.

Please don't call it that way; it's confusing. Call it `PlantView`, so a casual reader of your code is aware of what the class is supposed to do. Similarly, you might want to call the variables `plantView` instead of `plantScreen`, and `plantNameLabel` instead of `plantName`. `plantScreen` implies a variable containing `UIScreen`, and `plantName` implies an `NSString` more than it implies a `UILabel`. Same applies to `quantity`; call this variable `quantityLabel`.

Next, let's consider what the variables are depending on -- their origin's `x` and `y` do not change based on the counter, variable `i`. Perhaps you meant to write:

```
UILabel *plantName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((plantScreen.frame.origin.x), (plantScreen.frame.origin.y+ plantScreen.frame.size.height * i), 160, 30.0)];
```

and later on:

```
UILabel *quantity = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((plantScreen.frame.origin.x), (plantScreen.frame.origin.y+ plantScreen.frame.size.height*i + 20), 160, 30.0)];
```

Next, *avoid exceptions and exception handling*. Ensure that the exception does not occur via other forms of checking; Apple [highly recommends](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Exceptions.html) you fix exceptions while writing the application and not handle them when they run:

> **Important:** You should reserve the use of exceptions for programming or
>   unexpected runtime errors such as out-of-bounds collection access,
>   attempts to mutate immutable objects, sending an invalid message, and
>   losing the connection to the window server. You usually take care of
>   these sorts of errors with exceptions when an application is being
>   created rather than at runtime.

Next, a small stylistic remark (not very important): you're mixing calling setters via properties and calling setters directly. Nothing wrong (they end up doing exactly the same), but stylistically not very nice.

Next, unless you're using ARC (automatic reference counting), don't forget to release the views once they're added as subviews.

Next, `plantScreen` (which I named `plantView` below) can have type set to `Plant` (which I named `PlantView` below) when declared inside the loop.

Last but highly important and **extremely** easy to miss: you call the function `isMemberOfClass:` instead of `isKindOfClass:`.

Reworked version of your code (untested):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    int i = 0;
    for (PlantView *plantView in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([plantView isKindOfClass:[PlantView class]])
        {
            //the label which will hold the name
            CGRect plantNameLabelFrame = CGRectMake((plantScreenView.frame.origin.x),
                                                   (plantScreenView.frame.origin.y + plantScreen.frame.size.height*i), 
                                                  160, 
                                                  30.0);
            UILabel *plantNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: plantNameLabelFrame];
            plantNameLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
            plantNameLabel.minimumScaleFactor = .5;
            plantNameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            plantNameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            plantNameLabel.backgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor];

            [self.view addSubview:plantNameLabel];
            [plantNameLabel release];

            //create the label which will hold the quantity
            CGRect quantityLabelFrame = CGRectMake((plantScreenView.frame.origin.x),
                                                      (plantScreenView.frame.origin.y + plantScreen.frame.size.height*i + 20), 
                                                      160, 
                                                      30.0);
            UILabel *quantityLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: quantityLabelFrame];
            quantityLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            quantityLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            quantityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", plant.quantity]; // NB: what's "plant"?
            [self.view addSubview:quantityLabel];

            i++;
       }
    }
}
```

I've also removed `.hidden = false` (which should actually read `.hidden = NO`; this is Objective-C, and not C++), and `bringSubviewToFront:` (it's already in front, having just been added by `addSubview:`).

Comment: I put it in there, I will be sure to let the superclass to its magic in the future! I also tested moving it to -loadview, but it made no difference. I have it in viewwillappear because I need it to run each time I tab to this view. Thanks for the input though! Any other thoughts?

Comment: Having looked a lot more into your code, it's a confusing piece. I tried to figure out what you WANTED to say, and I tried fixing it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Frame of the `UIImageView` depends on the image being drawn and its `contentMode` property. You can try setting the `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` to see if it forces to keep its assigned frame.

Comment: I see what you are saying, however, this is an issue with the location that the UILabel is initially generated in as opposed to the UIImageView's actual content. I only care about the location of the UIImageView. On first load, it sets it to the top left corner of the iPad, the {0,0} origin.